# Retrieving properties from an object in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm very new to PHP, and I'm sorry if this is a very stupid question.

I'm working with cakePHP and I have the below code inside a method in `/src/Controller/CommentsController.php`:

```
$comment = $this->Comments->get($id, [
    'contain' => []
]);
```

When I `debug($comment)` I get something like:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Comment) {
    'new' => false,
    'accessible' => [
        'user_id' => true,
        'commentary' => true,
        'user' => true
    ],
    'properties' => [
        'id' => (int) 3,
        'user_id' => (int) 2,
        'commentary' => 'Hello World!',
        'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {
            'time' => '2014-12-02T18:53:52+0000',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'fixedNowTime' => false
        },
        'updated' => null
    ],
    'dirty' => [],
    'original' => [],
    'virtual' => [],
    'errors' => [],
    'repository' => 'Comments'
}
```

I need to compare that `'user_id'` inside `'properties'` to another variable, but I don't know how to access the properties of the object `$comment`. I've tried `$comment->properties` and `$comment['properties']`, but both return `null`. How would you access those properties?

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessing-entity-data**

Comment: The properties are essentially the fields of a table record identified by id. You can access any property like this: `$comment->user_id`.

Comment: Omg that worked. Thank you very much! But I didn't understand why :/